# how to pass parameters with like clause and regular expression in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am developing an application using nodejs and neo4j. I have to execute the following query with the parameters but this doesn't give result for where pi.genenames  =~ '.*$nameParam.*'

```
Match (pi:proteinidentifier)-[pe:proteinidentifier_has_a_ensembleprotein]-> (e:ensembleprotein)
-[ppi:on_interaction_with]->(en:ensembleprotein)-[ep:ensembleprotein_has_a_proteinidentifier]-(pi2:proteinidentifier) 
where pi.genenames  =~ '.*$nameParam.*' OR pi.uniprot =  $nameParam OR pi.ensembleprotein =  $nameParam 
return pi,pe,e,ppi,en,ep,pi2  limit $limitval
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher does not parse string literals to do [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) replacement.

That is why this does not work:

```
pi.genenames =~ '.*$nameParam.*'
```

However, here is a workaround that does work:

```
pi.genenames =~ ('.*' + $nameParam + '.*')
```

*But the `CONTAINS` function is a better way of handling your use case.*

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.*$nameParam.*` doesn't evaluate to the desired string within cypher.
Try to pass the whole expression including `*.` so that the like clause looks like this:

```
=~ $nameParamRegex
```

Alternatively, you could use the `contains` keyword if the regex is as simple as here:

`where pi.genenames contains $nameParam OR pi.uniprot = $nameParam` etc.